# leer archivo mediante html y javascript programaticamente

Tags: javascript, html

1) Tengo un archivo sqlite con información
2) Mediante un programa genero un archivo *.csv.

Quisiera en una NetBook o iPad o CromeCast o Celula,r mostrar dicha información en forma secuencial o a requerimiento del usuario.

Por ejemplo si el usuario utiliza: 
+, flecha derecha o flecha arriba: avanzar de 1 en 1
-, flecha abajo, o flecha izquierda: retroceder de 1 en 1
home: ir al inicio
end: ir al final
si escribe un número y luego enter ir a la linea correspondiente

No deseo instalar un servicio apache ni usar iis, pero si utilizar el navegador.

Mediante html y javascript he conseguido hacerlo pero el usuario antes de comenzar debe seleccionar el archivo.csv

Quisiera que al clickear sobre el archivo.html o sobre un acceso directo que se encuentre en el escritorio no fuera necesario seleccionar el archivo.csv.

Lo que he encontrado en la web me ha permitido hacer esto:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
<div>
    Seleccionar Archivo: 
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
</div>

    <input type = 'text' value= '1' id='txtLote' onkeypress="return         runScript(event)"  onkeyup="runScript(event)"style="text-align:right;"/>

<pre id="fileDisplayArea"></pre>
    <div id="divData" style="font-size:50px">

    </div>
</div>
<style>
    input:focus { 
       background-color: yellow;
    }
    body{
        font-family: courier;
   }
.tbl{font-size:50px;
font-weight: bold}
</style>
<script>
var nwLote = 0;
var array;
var maxArray;
document.getElementById("txtLote").focus();
document.getElementById("txtLote").select();

function runScript(e) 
{ 
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        {
    var tb = document.getElementById("txtLote");
    nwLote = tb.value;
    if (nwLote > maxArray)
    {
        nwLote = maxArray;
    }
    if (nwLote < 1)
    {
        nwLote = 1;
    }
    mostrarDato(nwLote);
    return false;
}
if (e.keyCode == 43) // +
{
    nwLote = + nwLote + 1;
    if (nwLote > maxArray)
    {
        nwLote = maxArray;
    }
    document.getElementById("txtLote").value=nwLote;    
    mostrarDato(nwLote);
    return false;
}
if (e.keyCode == 45) // -
{
    nwLote = nwLote - 1;
    if (nwLote < 1)
    {
        nwLote = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("txtLote").value=nwLote;    
    mostrarDato(nwLote);
    return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) // derecha
    {
    nwLote = + nwLote + 1;
    if (nwLote > maxArray)
    {
        nwLote = maxArray;
    }
    document.getElementById("txtLote").value=nwLote;    
    mostrarDato(nwLote);
    return false;
}
    if (e.keyCode == 37) // izquierda
    {
     nwLote = nwLote - 1;
    if (nwLote < 1)
    {
        nwLote = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("txtLote").value=nwLote;    
    mostrarDato(nwLote);
    return false;
}
    if (e.keyCode == 38) // arriba
    {
    nwLote = + nwLote + 1;
    if (nwLote > maxArray)
    {
        nwLote = maxArray;
    }
    document.getElementById("txtLote").value=nwLote;    
    mostrarDato(nwLote);
    return false;
}
    if (e.keyCode == 40) // abajo
    {
    nwLote = nwLote - 1;
    if (nwLote < 1)
    {
        nwLote = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("txtLote").value=nwLote;    
    mostrarDato(nwLote);
    return false;
}
    if (e.keyCode == 36) // home
    {
    nwLote = 1;
    document.getElementById("txtLote").value=nwLote;       
    mostrarDato(nwLote);
    return false;
}
    if (e.keyCode == 35) // end
    {
    nwLote = maxArray;  
    document.getElementById("txtLote").value=nwLote;    
    mostrarDato(nwLote);       
    return false;
}
    return true;
}
function mostrarDato(nwLote){
var divData = document.getElementById('divData');
var string = array[nwLote-1] ;
var array1 = string.split(",");
var contenido = "<table class='tbl'>";
contenido += "<tr><td>LOTE</td><td>" + array1[0] + "</td></tr>";
contenido += "<tr><td>DETALLE</td><td>" + array1[1] + "</td></tr>";
contenido += "<tr><td>CANTIDAD&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>" + array1[2] + "</td></tr>";
contenido += "<tr><td>BASE</td><td>" + array1[3] + "</td></tr>";
contenido += "<tr><td>REMITE</td><td>" + array1[6] + "</td></tr>";
contenido += "<tr><td>REMITO</td><td>" + array1[4] + "</td></tr>";
contenido += "<tr><td>RENGLON</td><td>" + array1[5] + "</td></tr>";
contenido += "</table>";

divData.innerHTML = contenido;
document.getElementById("txtLote").focus();
document.getElementById("txtLote").select();    
}
window.onload = function() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var textType = /text.*/;

    if (file.type.match(textType)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var string = reader.result ;
            array = string.split("|");
            maxArray = array.length-1;
            var string1 = array[0] ;
            var array1 = string1.split(",");
            var contenido = "<table class='tbl'>";
            contenido += "<tr><td>LOTE</td><td>" + array1[0] + "</td></tr>";
            contenido += "<tr><td>DETALLE</td><td>" + array1[1] + "</td>        </tr>";
            contenido += "<tr><td>CANTIDAD&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>" + array1[2] + "</td></tr>";
            contenido += "<tr><td>BASE</td><td>" + array1[3] + "</td></tr>";
            contenido += "<tr><td>REMITE</td><td>" + array1[6] + "</td></tr>";
            contenido += "<tr><td>REMITO</td><td>" + array1[4] + "</td></tr>";
            contenido += "<tr><td>RENGLON</td><td>" + array1[5] + "</td></tr>";
            contenido += "</table>";
            divData.innerHTML = contenido;
            document.getElementById("txtLote").focus();
            document.getElementById("txtLote").select();
        }

        reader.readAsText(file);    
    } else {
        fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
    }
});
}
</script>
```

He encontrado muchos sitios donde se informa que en html5 no se puede acceder a un archivo por un tema de seguridad (en forma programatica), que es necesario darle al usuario la posibilidad de buscar dicho archivo mediante el "input" que se encuentra al principio del código.

PREGUNTA A)
A mi me parece mucho más inseguro que el usuario busque el archivo, no entiendo por qué dicen que es más seguro ?

PREGUNTA B)
Existe forma de acceder a dicho archivo sin necesidad del "input", indicando por programación cuál es el archivo y como se haría ?

Todo esto utilizando HTML y javascript.

Aqui les dejo parte del archivo.csv para que puedan probarlo.

1, TV 14,       0.00,      1,     337721,   7, QUORTIONI RUBEN|   2, SOBRES DE NYLON,       0.00,    400,     337656,  25, PEREZ LUIS|   3, LOTE CON PERCHAS,       0.00,      1,     337664,   1, RODOLFO REY|   4, CAJON DE MADERA VALIJA,       0.00,      1,     337723,   5, COLOMBO CARMELO|   5, GANCHOS PARA TABLERO,       0.00,     60,     337656,  24, PEREZ LUIS|   6, SOPORTE P/TV,       0.00,      1,     337726,   5, TAMBORINI CARLOS|   7, LOTE C/REVISTAS,       0.00,      1,     337727,   8, VARELA ANA|   8, EQUIPO DE MUSICA C/6 PARLANTES,       0.00,      1,     337723,   8, COLOMBO CARMELO|   9, LOTES C/LIBROS,       0.00,      2,     337707,  16, PEREYRA ANDRES|

Comment: No, que una web pueda descargarse automáticamente un archivo del usuario sin su permiso explícito no es seguro.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví, el archivo no se descarga, solo se lee su contenido y se pasa a un array, para luego recorrerlo, es como cuando ingresas información de un usuario e ingresas el país, la lista de países se carga automaticamente y luego el usuario elige la opción.

Comment: Si Javascript puede cargar un archivo, puede enviarlo a un servidor, no es seguro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PREGUNTA A) A mi me parece mucho más inseguro que el usuario busque el archivo, no entiendo por qué dicen que es más seguro ?

Al ser manual, **el usuario decide que hacer**, puede por ejemplo decidir abrir en archivo "equis.csv" el sirve para completar el trabajo en cuestión, pero no abrir otro llamado "secreto.csv".. en cambio, en un proceso automático o de fondo, es el programa el que tomaría la decision y por ello ni siquiera esta permitido.

> PREGUNTA B) Existe forma de acceder a dicho archivo sin necesidad del "input", indicando por programación cuál es el archivo y como se haría ?

Es posible si creas una extension de navegador, pero no sería una página en si y tampoco funcionara en todos los navegadores de la misma forma ni si quiera con el mismo código pues cada uno tiene su propia API y forma de empaquetar la extension. Ademas algunos navegadores te limitan a cierto grupo de carpetas específicos donde puedes buscar o abrir los archivos. Ten en cuenta que para instalar una extension, hace falta una decision del usuario.

Otra opción es embeber tu pagina como una aplicación basada en Apache Cordoba (o hijos), pero esto requiere el paso de la instalación, que también incluye una decision del usuario.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta a la Pregunta A

**El navegador está del lado del usuario y defiende sus intereses**. Y no está del lado del programador. ¿Por qué? porque podría haber un programador deshonesto (incluso dentro de un grupo de programadores honestos) que en una parte del programa vaya a buscar por todo el disco del usuario los archivos que parezcan privados (agenda.xls, etc) y se los envíe al servidor para espiar a los usuarios.

(Salvo errores de seguridad eventuales) uno debería estar más o menos seguro que usando Firefox (o Chrome o cualquiera de los navegadores más prestigiosos) no podría ocurrir algo así (salvo que uno use una versión vieja o que le haya instalado extensiones o pluggins de las que no se puede garantizar qué es lo que están haciendo).

## Respuesta a la pregunta B

No usando HTML5 y el Javascript en su versión actual. Sí programando extensiones. Si el programa que estás diseñando es para que lo usen solamente gente que te tiene extrema confianza, los puedes convencer de que instalen esa extensión.

Pero si tienes esa confianza puedes explicarles que lo hagan de la buena manera (especificando el archivo). También se puede usar "arrastrar y soltar" (drag and drop) sobre algún área de tu página para que tome el nombre del archivo. Igual es el usuario el que lo tiene que elegir