# Escribir en un archivo texto con javascript

Tags: javascript

Como puedo escribir en un archivo texto, con javascript.
Tengo este codigo pero no me funciona:

```
function WriteFile(filename, data)
        {
            var FileOpener = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var FilePointer = FileOpener.OpenTextFile(filename, 2, false);
            FilePointer.WriteLine(data);
            FilePointer.Close();
        }
```

Comment: tu respuesta puede estar aquí http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/15511/6635

Comment: Ojo! ActiveXObject es solo para Internet Explorer. Si planeas usar esa configuración **en otros navegadores no va funcionar**. Aparte, por motivos de seguridad no se puede guardar archivos sin intervencion del usuario. fijate aqui tambien: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/16905

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta corta es "no puedes".

La respuesta larga es: No hay una manera estándar para escribir ficheros (en la máquina donde se ejecuta el navegador), que funcione bien en todos los navegadores mayoritarios.

El método de activex te servirá para IE (no para Edge). Mozilla tiene [`FileHandle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_Handle_API) para Firefox, y Google tiene [`FileWriter`](http://caniuse.com/#search=filesystem) para Chrome.

Nótese que no hay ninguna manera (fiable) de hacer que Safari o Edge escriban ficheros.

Te sugiero que leas también https://w3c.github.io/filesystem-api/, y https://stackoverflow.com/a/6723450.

Answer (score 0):

A partir de HTML5 se puede leer archivos.
Por medio de la API File.
Esta es la documentación oficial
https://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/

Para escribir en archivos desde el navegador es un poco mas complejo.
Te dejo este video donde puedes ver como funciona la API File en el caso que necesites escribir en archivos.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9g-KyT4Ieg